# Is there a software solution to plug off the laptop?

Tags: battery, laptop, hp

Is it possible to plug off the laptop by a command from the laptop, rather than by removing the adapter from power source?

I am on Windows Seven, but I will also welcome any note regarding the existence of such command for some version of Linux.

My laptop is hp g71.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible.
Look at the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091775/how-can-i-programmatically-stop-a-notebook-battery-from-charging

One more thing to notice is that the battery charging is independent of OS and also happens when the System is Powered Off. Thus if there be any setting of kind it would need to be done in firmware or via a proprietary software from the laptop vendor which changes the firmware entries.

I also have an HP Laptop and haven't seen any such utility on the HP Software downloads page.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood I should remove my answer then.